# osisoft updating values ​with python

Tags: osisoft

I want to get the data from Excel and update the values ​​of the data between certain dates in the osisoft system. But I don't know how to code AfTimeRange.
I get the error "value cannot be converted to OSIsoft.AF.Time.AFTime".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nfEK.jpg)

Comment: You should add the code as plain text, not screenshot.

Comment: How are you trying to update the data in pi? Through the Web API or an SDK?

Comment: You could get more assistance if we had a link to the actual SDK library. Also, please write the code directly instead of just attaching an image link.

Answer (score 0):

Good news: You've constructed your [AFTimeRange] correctly!

Notice that the error being thrown is not by the [AFTimeRange] constructor, but from something else.

The issue is that you are trying to set the 'Timestamp' attribute  [OSIsoft.AF.Time.AFTime] to a value of type [OSIsoft.AF.Time.AFTimeRange], and so it's failing. A PI event has a single timestamp, not a time range.

I'm not familiar with Python, but it should work if you input the value as an AFTime object using its string constructor, assuming you're intending to use *yesterday midnight* as your timestamp:

```
val.timestamp = AFTime("y")
```

[See the documentation on AFTime](https://docs.osisoft.com/bundle/af-sdk/page/html/M_OSIsoft_AF_Time_AFTime__ctor_7.htm) for more detail.